# How to decypher the filesize of a native c# dll?

Tags: c#, uwp, exe, native

We have a game that we are making for the windows store. As this is for the windows store it gets natively compiled into a native exe.

For some reason this exe is almost 40mb and we don't have any embedded resources in it.

When I open the exe using 7zip I find this inside it but I cannot find out what any of it means.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to reduce the size of this exe? Its size is a significant issue.

Comment: Those are sections in the PE file. The ".text" section contains the code, for instance. The ".reloc" is for linking I think. The "*data" sections should contain data needed by the code (like strings). What's in the ".rsrc" folder and how big are its contents?

Comment: The .NET Native image does not contain just your program, it includes the entire .NET Framework.  So 40 MB is rather small.  It knows how to keep it that small by only including the framework methods that you actually use in your program.  If the size really matters to you (of course it doesn't) then consider to write Store apps in C++.